# How to link Essentia audio package from Home-brew to an Anaconda venv to call Essentia package using Juypter

Tags: python-3.x, macos, anaconda, homebrew

I want to use the Essentia Audio for fun.  toolshttps://essentia.upf.edu/documentation/download.html

My system is Mac using 10.14.6

I am a relative newbie and have been using Juypter via Anaconda3 with Python3. I am self-taught on Terminal, Python, and  Anaconda (self-taught in that I use trial and error and back-up a lot. I have no idea what I am doing as this is not my field of expertise at all.)

When I download Essentia to Homebrew as per instructions, everything looks good.

When I try to call Essesntia inside Jupyter
     import essentia
     import essentia.standard as es

the response is no module named essentia.

Essentia is located /usr/local/Cellar/essentia/HEAD-53c2fdb/bin/essentia_standard_beatsmarker

But is is also located /usr/local/bin/essentia_standard_beatsmarker

I would like to work through the practice code written here https://essentia.upf.edu/documentation/essentia_python_examples.html#fingerprinting

When that didn't work, I copied the Essentia file into anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/essentia/

From inside Juypter, I opened a new terminal page located the essentia package (anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/essentia/), and from this location, I input Python3 setup.py install. Everything looked ok.

Inside the Juypter Notebook, I then call import essentia which worked but when I tried to call import essentia.standard as es it didn't.

Then I did the same thing but inside the virtual environment set-up in anaconda3.

so anaconda3/envs/python-cv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/essentia-2.1_beta5.

From inside Juypter, I opened a new terminal page located the essentia package (anaconda3/envs/python-cv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/essentia-2.1_beta5), and from this location, I input Python3 setup.py install. Everything looked ok.

Inside the Juypter Notebook, I then call import essentia which didn't work.

So then I panicked and rolled back the time machine three days before I started messing around trying to install Essentia using Homebrew.

What should I do to fix this? There are random essentia files all over the place how can I scrub this and do it properly, please? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From issues in official github. essentia with python (specially anaconda env) only work for linux so far. Highly recommended on official docker image to build a docker container and project your jupyter notebook in the [container](https://essentia.upf.edu/download.html).